# как сделать так, чтобы бот искал информацию в интернате и выдавал первые 5 ссылок с ответом на ваш запрос

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Первый раз пишу бота на Python для телеграмм. Нужно, чтобы бот умел искать информацию допустим из яндекса(если так можно) и выдавал тебе первые 5 ссылок по твоему запросу

Comment: Парсинг? Копайте в сторону requests, beatifulSoup или requests-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл вот [тут](https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-scrape-google-search-results-using-python) парсинг результатов Google. Добавил условие на 5 ссылок

```py
import urllib
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession


def get_source(url):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        response = session.get(url)
        return response

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)

def scrape_google(query):

    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
    response = get_source("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query)

    links = list(response.html.absolute_links)
    google_domains = ('https://www.google.',
                      'https://google.',
                      'https://webcache.googleusercontent.',
                      'http://webcache.googleusercontent.',
                      'https://policies.google.',
                      'https://support.google.',
                      'https://maps.google.')

    for url in links[:]:
        if url.startswith(google_domains):
            links.remove(url)

    return links

def get_results(query):
    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
    response = get_source("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query)

    return response

def parse_results(response):
    css_identifier_result = ".tF2Cxc"
    css_identifier_title = "h3"
    css_identifier_link = ".yuRUbf a"
    css_identifier_text = ".VwiC3b"

    results = response.html.find(css_identifier_result)

    output = []

    i = 0
    for result in results:
        item = {
            'title': result.find(css_identifier_title, first=True).text, #заголовок
            'link': result.find(css_identifier_link, first=True).attrs['href'], #ссылка
            'text': result.find(css_identifier_text, first=True).text #краткое описание
        }

        output.append(item)

        #берем именно 5 ссылок
        i += 1

        if i >= 5:
            break

    return output


def google_search(query):
    response = get_results(query)
    return parse_results(response)


results = google_search("ВАШ ЗАПРОС")
print(results)
```

Если вдруг при установке `requests_html` будет ошибка `Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?`, то переходите [сюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) и качаете файл для своей версии `Python` и нужной разрядности системы (для меня, например, это `lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl` - версия 3.11 и 64-х разрядная система). Затем устанавливаете его `pip install Диск:\путь\до\скачанного\файла\lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`